# How do you name order scope of the Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have naming question.

Suppose if we have these kind of scopes in model of Rails3 application,

```
scope :order_by_date,      order("created_at asc")
scope :order_by_date_desc, order("created_at desc")
```

The name of scope is too long and explanatory as scope.

```
scope :ordered,      order("created_at asc")
```

But if we define as above, it's difficult to distinguish between asc or desc.

So how do you use scope such a case? or do you use scope?

Does anyone have good idea?

Thanks.

Comment: why not just `Model.date_desc` ?

Comment: Model.date_desc is nice! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well...

```
Model.ascending_order
Model.descending_order
```

Comment: Not bad, but I'd ask: ascending order of *what*? `Model.ascending_date_order` would be my preference, but that's a bit long, too (plus, what if the model has two dates you could order by?). Greg Guida's comment above of `Model.date_asc` is probably more to the liking of the OP.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it is missing the attribute. Although long, i believe it is more descriptive with `ascending` and `descending`.

Comment: Agreed. I personally don't mind long method names, but everyone has their own style, I guess.

Comment: It's helpful for me! Thanks to you guys!